# Reading a hosted PDF file from a URL and converting to text in iOS using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I am reading a PDF file stored locally (using nsbundle) and converting it to text.

But when I am trying to read the PDF from http i.e. URL scheme and give the path to my PDF to text converter it returns nil.
Any solutions would be appreciated.

My basic question is how to read a PDF file from a URL path?

Answer (score 0):

on that way there are many restriction to convert PDF file to plain text.If you want to display PDF on app then use [PDF Reader Core](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

Comment: Maybe you could download the pdf from the url before converting it and delete the pdf file when the conversion is doene

Comment: @LoVo this could be done. I will give it a shot and if am successful a big thank you to you.  My only worry will be it should not consume more memory. Thank you